# Updating an integer field of a Rails model with string strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, strong-parameters

In my controller, I want to update the fields to my model object in my update method. Some of the fields of my model are of the integer type. However, these fields are strings in the params object.

I would like to do

```rb
  def profile_params
    params
      .require(:client)
      .permit(:marital_status, :name, ...)
  end

  def update
    @client = Client.find params[:id]
    @client = Client.update(profile_params)
  end
```

But I get the following error

> ArgumentError - '0' is not a valid marital_status.

Sure enough, if inside my `profile_params.rb` I cast `marital_status` as an integer, that particular error goes away, but I have a lot of fields in my `Client` class that are integers.  I'm imagining there's a better solution than just manually casting each field. Or even if I have to, what is the best way to organize my code?

Edit: This is a summary of the client model

```rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord

  enum marital_status: %i[single married divorced separated widowed]

end
```

and the params passed to the controller look like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tLUZ0bb6tRRkx/OFNVbhCT/AnrudPbCQMvOakw9HyiHkiqMip5tkDnYsF2F/e7TE4VkmIgF1hxtYI78Pw2bsSw==", "client"=>{"id"=>"517", "marital_status"=>"0"}, "id"=>"517"}
```

Comment: show your profile_params.rb, your database migration, and your input form

Comment: Sounds like that (and maybe the others) are Enums, is that correct?

Comment: Agree with @RockwellRice, `marital_status` is an `enum` though he didn't show his model. the `marital_status` in  `param` is `nil` and thus it converting `nil` into `0` which is not present in the `enum`

Comment: Thanks for all your input; I've updated my question. The input coming in from the form is actually a "0" string.

Comment: Show us the form-element to select the status?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's no other way than to use `.to_i` when reading the values from `profile_params`.

Enums are tricky because you can use them either by the key or the by the value.

Assuming your enum:

```rb
Client.marital_statuses
#  => {"single"=>0, "married"=>1, "divorced"=>2, "separated"=>3, "widowed"=>4}
```

Assignment using the value (index):

```rb
c1 = Client.new
c1.marital_status = 0
c1.marital_status
#  => "single"
c1.marital_status_before_type_cast
#  => 0
```

Assignment using the key (name):

```rb
c2 = Client.new
c2.marital_status = 'married'
c2.marital_status
#  => "married"
c2.marital_status_before_type_cast
#  => "married"
```

I think that's the reason why Rails doesn't cast a String to Integer, because it doesn't know that it should use the value (index) instead of the key (name).

```rb
c3 = Client.new
c3.marital_status = '0'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#         2: from (irb):6
#         1: from (irb):7:in `rescue in irb_binding'
# ArgumentError ('0' is not a valid marital_status)
```